# Backup with rsnapshot only if there are changes

Tags: rsync, backup, rsnapshot

I use `rsnapshot` to make regular backups of my systems' filesystems to a remote server.

(For those familiar with `rsync` but less used to `rsnapshot` here is a brief introduction to its workings. A backup is a file-by-file copy of a source file-system tree, much like `cp -a` would produce. The "current" backup is always `hourly.0`, and the previous one is `hourly.1`. These names are rotated each time a backup begins. Under the covers `rsnapshot` uses `rsync --link-dest` to hardlink unchanged files in `hourly.0` to the corresponding entries in the previous backup tree, `hourly.1`.)

If a backup fails, the previous backup is copied (linked) using `cp -al` to the current backup, so that a backup always appears to have been made.

What I would like is to avoid making a backup if there have been no changes since the previous backup. This could include a backup failure or simply that the source filesystem was not modified since the last backup. ("Making a backup" can be rephrased to "deleting an unnecessary backup" if you would prefer.)

I've considered looking in the `hourly.0` tree for files that are not hard-linked elsewhere, and if there is none then simply deleting the backup tree. This does not handle a file that is validly linked elsewhere within its backup, and it also fails to consider changes to directories. I have also considered using `rsync --dry-run` to compare the two backup trees and looking at its output but this feels somewhat ugly.

Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After the snapshot, you can use `rsnapshot diff` which calls `rsnapshot-diff` to note the differences between two snapshots. It just compares inode numbers so is fairly efficient.

Alternatively, before each backup create a file outside the backup tree to note the time, `touch timestamp`. Then before a new backup, create a new timestamp, `touch timestamp.new`, and test if any files or directories have a newer time than the old timestamp

```
find tree -newer timestamp
```

If not, do not do the backup. In any case, `mv timestamp.new timestamp` for the next time. This assumes you don't have applications that manipulate the file and directory timestamps.

Answer (score 0):

I have also considered this as a possibility, which is more generic than the excellent [proposals](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/275968/100397) I've accepted from [meuh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/119298/meuh).

```
listfiles()
{
    (
        # List attributes of file tree, discarding inode number
        cd "$1" 2>/dev/null && find . -type f -ls | sed -r 's/^ *[1-9][0-9]*//' | sort
    )
}

listfiles hourly.1 >/tmp/list1
listfiles hourly.0 >/tmp/list0
cmp -s /tmp/list1 /tmp/list0 && echo "the same" || echo "different"
```

This also ignores ACLs and Extended Attributes associated with a file but not listed with `find -ls`. However, for my purposes this would have been acceptable.